# "Failed building wheel for psycopg2==2.8.6" - MacOSX using virtualenv and pip

Tags: python, django, postgresql, macos, psycopg2

I need install psycopg2==2.8.6 because when I installed latest version I get UTC error.
I solve UTC error with install psycopg2==2.8.6 in my manjaro os but i try install this in my macOS and i got this:

```
  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/'
  ld: library not found for -lssl
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2

Comment: have you tried with pip install psycopg2-binary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install psycopg2 on MacOS M1 and python 3.10.5 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73042760/pip-install-psycopg2-on-macos-m1-and-python-3-10-5-not-working)

Comment: @JavierLopezTomas yes i tried and got same error.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer no, i tried this and i got same error.

Comment: @Mahyar Kakavand: No. The linker cannot find openssl, that is what is decribed in the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

In case of M1 Macs:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include $LDFLAGS"
pip install psycopg2==2.8.6
```

In case of Intel Macs:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
pip install psycopg2==2.8.6
```

It should work if you installed OpenSSL via brew `brew install openssl`. If not, please update `psycopg2` to lastest version (`2.9.3` for this moment) - it won't break anything.

Comment: i tried this and got same error :(

Comment: Do you own M1 based or Intel Mac? I updated the answer in-case of using x86 counterpart.