# Trouble installing psycopg2 on Mac

Tags: django, heroku, pip, psycopg2

I'm pretty new to developing and have found some errors while trying to deploy my django project on heroku. I'm trying to download the django-heroku package with pip but keep running into this error:
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib'
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
ERROR: Could not build wheels for psycopg2, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I've tried so many things, exhausted chatGBT, and have read so many articles. I've tried reinstalling openssl and using these commands:
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"

I've also tried installing psycopg2-binary which worked, only to find that installing django-heroku requires psycog2. I tried installing django-heroku with no dependencies, but it still requires pspycopg2.

I've tried upgrading home-brew, pip, the pip setup, and so much more. All the articles on this are pretty old so some fresh eyes would help! I'm using macOS Ventura 13.4.1. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/prakashanantha/f957e6a9a193ac1bd8bf

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73042760/pip-install-psycopg2-on-macos-m1-and-python-3-10-5-not-working/73054093#73054093

Answer (score 2):

I asked a co-worker and he helped me out a bit. I have an M1 mac and I needed to install xcode command line tools to get more access to my computer. After that, this article helped me a bunch. [error installing psycopg2, library not found for -lssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288042/error-installing-psycopg2-library-not-found-for-lssl)